# What is the average time distribution of reputation accrual?

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics, incentive, motivation

I am wondering if anyone has analyzed average reputation points accrued over time.

Given that posting a good answer to a question will accrue a total of x points over a year, I imagine there must be some kind of curve that looks like this, on average:

- first 30% of total reputation points accrued within 12 hours
- add'l 20% accrued hours 12-24 (cumulative 50% within a day after posting)
- add'l 20% accrued days 2-7 (cumulative 70% within first week)
- add'l 15% accrued days 8-30 (cumulative 85% within first month)
- final 15% accrued months 2-12

And I imagine the curve could be somewhat different, depending on different factors:

- Stack Exchange community (Stack Overflow, Meta, etc.)
- Whether the answer was accepted
- Number of upvotes given to the question (within first hour, day, week, etc.)
- Number of answers at time of posting
- Reputation score of the person providing the answer
- etc...

I'm getting more involved in the Stack Overflow community, and it would be interesting to estimate the total value of my activity, based on the early response.

If I spend an hour answering questions, and a day later I see that I got 50 reputation points from that activity, what's the long-term value? Can I expect it to "grow" from 50 to 80 over the next month, or year? Or to 100? Maybe 150?

Comment: Oh, this would be a fun little project... I'll bet it varies quite a bit by tag too. If you're good with SQL, check out http://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I found an [existing query on data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483654/user-reputation-history), maybe this is what you are looking for?

The query displays the reputation grouped by date, not exactly the kind of *long-tail view* you are looking for but imported into a spreadsheet you could do a quick graph and check the reputation change for a single user.

[image: Reputation over time]

My SQL is not really enough to modify this query to build this graph over all users, especially not this early in the morning.